# Is there a reason to distinguish between the tags "ternary" and "trytes"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Today I approved an tag-edit adding the *ternary* tag to a question already tagged with *trytes*. I was torn between approving and outright rejecting it. Why?

It's less due to the edit itself (which is totally valid considering the two tags) but to the existence of both those tags. Now, I'm wondering what they are for exactly and if we need both. If I take a step back both seem to tackle the use of ternary computing in IOTA and background to ternary computing.

My suggestion would be to consolidate on one tag, *ternary* and make trits, trytes, trinary and the likes synonyms.

Is there any reason to keep both tags?

*Synonyms have been created and tags have been merged.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, no need for both tags at present. IMO, ternary is the tag to keep.